# How to set the imageview as the background image of my LinearLayout from Picasso image loader programmatically?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-imageview, picasso

I'm using `Picasso` class/library to load an image from an `url` and display the image to a `ImageView`. Is it possible for me to set the `imageview` loaded by the **picasso** image loader from an `url` as the background image of a `linearlayout` programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already found this issue - might be useful for you:

[How do i set background image with picasso in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777354/how-do-i-set-background-image-with-picasso-in-code)

According to that, Use callback of Picasso

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.table_background).into(new Target(){

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom from) {
       mainLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
        Log.d("TAG", "FAILED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Prepare Load");
    }      
})
```

Read also

[Set background resource using Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066292/set-background-resource-using-picasso)

but there would you find the same solution.

Comment: Sadly" new BitmapDrawable" is deprecated